# cannot install libapache2-mod-fcgid apache mod

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-fcgid

hello i trying to install libapache2-mod-fcgid mod but have always get error.

```
root@mail:~# sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-fcgid : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and without fcgid mod i cannot launch apache server

```
root@mail:~# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_fcgid.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_fcgid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

apache version 2.4

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: Ubuntu 21.10 in year 2022:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-fcgid
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late for a response but, since there is no answer yet, I'll put one.

In this situation, the dependencies from `libapache2-mod-fcgid` are not met. In this case, you could download and install `apache2.2-common` prior the installation of `libapache2-mod-fcgid` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
```

and then try your install command afterward.